# how to edit data in gridview

Tags: .net, gridview

i want to know about how to edit data into girdview, and what is the function of EditIndex properties.

Comment: Which language/platform? .NET?

Answer (score 1):

You can modify cell data like this:

```
GridView1.Rows[0].Cells[0].Text = "NewText";
```

> EditIndex property is used to
>   programmatically specify or determine
>   which row in a GridView control to
>   edit.

Check the [MSDN Support](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview.editindex%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) for both the EditIndex and Editdata in a gridview